# Cpanel - How to delete addon domain associated folder after removing domain?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, cpanel, ftp, folder

I have added and then removed few add-on domains in my hosting. But after deleting, their assigned folder still appears in folder and ftp listing. I tried to delete or rename them but they still appear after a day. I asked the hosting support but they have no answer how to remove them completely.

**Update:**

I did not setup any subdomain on any domain.

**Update 2:**

All folders already have 755 permissions, I can delete them successfully but they reappear the next day. I also deleted database and email accounts related to them. They have some other settings set-up which makes them reappear but I cant find what it is.

Comment: "hosting support have no answer"?! For "hosting support" that should be a trivial question. cPanel addon domains usually point to a subdomain (which points to the subfolder). Have you checked what subdomains you have configured?

Comment: @adamzane Can you use the same account you posted from to respond and edit the question with? As w3dk points out, when you create an [addon domain](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Addon+Domains) a subdomain and folder in the root directory corresponding to the name of the addon domain is created. Once you remove the addon domain, then that folder should be removed automatically. If not, then use the File Manager to delete it, or do so via FTP or SSH. As Herman Nz points out, perhaps changing the folder permissions will help with the interface, but by default shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @adamzane That's not normal behavior for cPanel, unless you initiated a restore from backup. Once they're deleted, they're deleted, so perhaps something is messed up in your cPanel installation. You'll need to follow this up with your hosting provider's support - they may have to do a clean install or re-image the server. Unfortunately questions seeking individual troubleshooting are considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

For not having proper reputation to add a comment, here I try to give suggestion that perhaps suit to your problem.

Try to change the `chmod` first into `755`, then try to delete them again.
That's all. 
:D